# Grab Urls of google pictures: Undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I'm trying to get list of `urls` of google pictures from console with this code

```
// pull down jquery into the JavaScript console
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

which throws

```
<script>
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"
</script>
```

and works fine, but the next code

```
// grab the URLs
var urls = $('.rg_di .rg_meta').map(function() { return JSON.parse($(this).text()).ou; });
```

throws `undefined` and I'm not sure what I makes wrong, could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```js
var urls = $('.rg_di .rg_meta').map(e=>JSON.parse($(e).text()).ou);
console.log(urls)
```

Comment: thanks, but it show this error msg:"VM92:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:67) at jquery.min.js:2 at Function.map (jquery.min.js:2) at n.fn.init.map (jquery.min.js:2) at <anonymous>:1:33" doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any value in your map function:

Try this:

```
var urls = $('.rg_di .rg_meta').map(function(value) { return JSON.parse($(value).text()).ou; });
```

Comment: thanks, but it show this error msg:"VM92:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
     at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:67)
     at jquery.min.js:2
     at Function.map (jquery.min.js:2)
     at n.fn.init.map (jquery.min.js:2)
     at <anonymous>:1:33"

doing something wrong?